# Scale HTML content and add scroll bars

Tags: css

If you've ever shrunk down your browser window, you'll notice that the webpage content shrinks down to some extent and then scroll bars start appearing. How is that done in CSS?

Comment: You don't need CSS. That just happens in any browser if the content of an HTML document doesn't fit in the viewport. Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for the [`min-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/min-width) property instead of a fixed `width`, so that the content can shrink down to a certain size.

```
.some-shrinkable-element {
   width: 30%;
   min-width: 100px;
}
```

This would create an element that is 30% the width of its parent, and will shrink as you make your window smaller, untill the element reaches 100px, then it stuck on that width.

Comment: I was writing the same thing at a time. :) And as @Moin Zaman said, it will also happen with a fixed width, when the browser window gets smaller than the content.

Comment: Also we need to add overflow: scroll; style, so that after reaching minimum size if window is still made smaller scroll bar will appear.

Comment: Yeah idk, it's not working. I can do it on this page; when you shrink down StackOverflow, the margins and whitespace to the left disappears first and then everything stays in place while the window gets smaller. That's what I'm going for.

Comment: @shadow I haven't looked through the CSS of SO, but I bet they use a fixed width for the content of the page and center it using `margin: 0 auto;`. When you decrease the window-size the browser will first decrease the margin until there is no margin left, then it will add a horizontal scroller.

Comment: I took the CSS from this page and just added it to mine to see and it still doesn't work. But thanks for the help guys.

Comment: @shadow I put together [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hscp3/). Is this the behavior you are looking for?

Comment: Sort of, except the content div in this case changes size. Here, I'll post a video showing what I mean. http://screencast.com/t/07sXw1844ryu

If you notice in the video, the content of the webpage never actually changes in size. Once it's been pushed to the edge of the page, it simply starts disappearing.

Comment: @shadow From the looks of it, they are using a combination of some elements that have 100% width (the top elements) and some content that is centered, and also has a min-width to force them to "disappear" at a certain window-size.